# Issue while running neo4j DriverManager.getConnection in linux

Tags: neo4j, jackson, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to connect to neo4j remote server ....My code works fine if I run it through windows....but when I make it as a runnable jar and trying to run in my centos it is throwing error...

```
            String line="060100B075|MOC|20150407|16:28:23|81|0628001735";       
            String[] cols = line.split("\\|");
            nodeCreation.createNodes(cols[0],cols[1],cols[2]);
```

//Createnode function

```
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://144.35.78.234:7474/");
            String Query = "MERGE (ABC:PLANE {name: " + "\""
                            + cols[0]+ "\"" + " }) RETURN ABC";
          try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(Query)) {
            ResultSet RS = stmt.executeQuery();
        }
```

I am able to connect from window and able to insert nodes from window..but not from linux environment..I dont think there is any issue with mycode..  How do i resolve this..

Snippet  of error like below:

```
Apr 14, 2015 6:41:19 PM org.restlet.engine.connector.ClientConnectionHelper start
INFO: Starting the internal [HTTP/1.1] client
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode.asText()Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.rest.Resources$DiscoveryClientResource.readInformation(Resources.java:153)
        at org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.rest.Resources.getDiscoveryResource(Resources.java:61)
        at org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.Neo4jConnection.createExecutor(Neo4jConnection.java:109)
        at org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.Neo4jConnection.<init>(Neo4jConnection.java:79)
        at org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.Connections$4.doCreate(Connections.java:65)
        at org.neo4j.jdbc.internal.Connections.create(Connections.java:80)
        at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:80)
        at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:42)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
        at com.emc.neo4jConnectivity.Test1.createNodes(Test1.java:39)
        at com.emc.neo4jConnectivity.HiveToNeo4jRemoteServer.main(HiveToNeo4jRemoteServer.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

This is how my pom.xml looks like:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
  </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This looks like a version mismatch error - the jdbc driver depends on jackson version `1.9.12`, can you verify that that is the version you're including in the jar?

Comment: @jakewins I am using 2.0.2 for neo4j-jdbc  and seems to jackson-core-asl-1.9.12 ,jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to share `mvn dependency:tree`, 
It might be that your hadoop lib pulls in a different version.

Also please learn about parameters in prepared statements and use `stmt.executeUpdate()`

```
  Connection con=
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://144.35.78.234:7474/");
  String query = "MERGE (plane:Plane {name: {1}}) RETURN plane";
  try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
    stmt.setString(1,cols[0]);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
  }
```

Comment: @michale..Thanks ..I checked..My hadoop lib has jackson 1.8.8 version and neo4j uses jackson 1.9.12...So how do i change my version because it downloads both the version...